# v-on with no argument expects an object value

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue. So I gotta tell ya, what I am doing here is working, but I am also get a dev tools error.

> [Vue warn]: v-on with no argument expects an object value.

Now, I get WHY it is telling me this, but when I try to fix it in a couple of ways, I get a number of errors. What I am wondering is how would I resolve this properly. I also want to stress what the code is doing IS working as expected on the frontend. Just not proper Vue I would like to resolve

TEMPLATE

```html
<div v-if="message.type === 'message'">
  <chat-message v-on="playMessageNotificationSound()" 
                :message="message"/>
</div>
<div v-else-if="message.type === 'notification'">
  <div v-show="this.$store.state.notifications.enterLeave === 'true'">
    <chat-notification v-on="playNotificationSound()" :message="message" />
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```js
methods: {
  playMessageNotificationSound() {
    if (this.$store.state.notifications.messagesound === 'true' ) {  
      var audio = new Audio('https://chat-cdn.levelupchat.com/chat-sounds/whisper.mp3');
      audio.volume = 0.4;
      audio.play();
    }
  },
  playNotificationSound () {
    if (this.$store.state.notifications.enterLeaveSound === 'true' ) {    
      var audio = new Audio('https://chat-cdn.levelupchat.com/chat-sounds/message.mp3');
      audio.volume = 0.4;
      audio.play();
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v-on is a directive to listen to DOM events and run some JavaScript when they’re triggered.
You can't use it empty instead need to bind an event handler .
**For example**

```
<button v-on:click="say('hi')">Say hi</button>
```

where

```
  methods: {
    say: function (message) {
      alert(message)
    }
  }
```

For more info : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events

Comment: I understand this, what I don't seem to grasp is while the code is working, its wrong, so how would I rewrite it so that it is Vue compliant without a bunch of errors. I just dont want a bunch of if statements up in the template.

Answer (score 0):

The [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) is intended for binding event listeners, but you're not actually trying to listen to any events, so you're misusing the `v-on` directive, leading to the warning you observed.

When Vue loads `<chat-message v-on="playNotificationSound()">`, it calls `playNotificationSound()`, expecting a return value to assign to `v-on`. Since `playNotificationSound()` is called when `chat-message` and `chat-notification` is rendered, it only appears to work as intended (the sound coincides with the chat message/notification).

However, there are no events to be handled here, so `v-on` should not be used. The call to `playNotificationSound()` should perhaps be moved into a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on `message.type`:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    'message.type'(messageType) {
      if (messageType === 'message') {
        this.playMessageNotificationSound()

      } else if (messageType === 'notification' && this.$store.state.notifications.enterLeave === 'true') {
        this.playNotificationSound()
      }
    }
  }
}
```